# как в jsf передать параметр в requestScoped managedBean

Tags: jsf

Нужно из одной страницы открыть другую, передав в ту "другую" параметр. "Другая" страница связана с RequestScoped бином.
на одной странице список "задач", а другая страница показывает детали по выбранной "задаче".

```
<h:commandButton  value="#{msg.details}" action="#{taskDetailsBean.showTaskDetail()}">
    <f:param name="taskId" value="#{task.dbID}"/>
</h:commandButton>
```

taskDetailsBean - это RequestScoped бин, в котором имеется функция

```
public String showTaskDetail(){
    FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    Map<String,String> params = fc.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
    this.taskId = params.get("taskId");

    return "task_details";
}
```

по нажатию на кнопку я перехожу на новую страницу, но подозреваю, что мой реквест бин создается дважды, потому как taskId - пуст..

подскажите пожалуйста, как нужно сделать в таком случае?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать метод с параметром:

```
<h:commandButton value="#{msg.details}" 
                 action="#{taskDetailsBean.showTaskDetail(task.dbID)}"/>
```

Метод:

```
public String showTaskDetail(String taskId) {
    this.taskId = taskId;
    return "task_details";
}
```

**Передача параметра через redirect с помощью viewParam**
1) Сделать целевую страницу с параметрами

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="taskId" value="#{taskDetailsBean.taskId}" />
</f:metadata>
```

Теперь можно принимать запросы такого вида:  http://server/app/task_details.xhtml?taskId=123
Параметр taskId будет автоматически записан в указанное свойство.
Осталось только научить action выдавать outcome с параметром.
2) Метод может вернуть такой outcome, чтобы параметры были включены в url get запроса:

```
public String showTaskDetail(String taskId) {
    this.taskId = taskId;
    return "task_details?faces-redirect=true&includeViewParams=true";
}
```

или такой:

```
public String showTaskDetail(String taskId) {
    this.taskId = taskId;
    return "task_details?faces-redirect=true&taskId=" + taskId;
}
```

**Передача через flash scope**
Flash хранит всё, что в него положат для следующего запроса. Следующий запрос может извлечь из него всё, что считает необходимым. Потом из flash-а всё пропадёт. Чтобы предать ещё дальше, надо класть в него заново.
1) В action методе сохранить параметр во flash

```
public String showTaskDetail(String taskId){
    this.taskId = taskId;
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getFlash().put("taskId", taskId);
    return "task_detail?faces-redirect=true";
}
```

2) В нужном месте (например в PostConstruct) извлечь из flash-а

```
@PostConstruct
private void postConstruct() {
    taskId = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getFlash().get("taskId");
    ...
}
```

**Сохранить параметр в session scope**
Даже не знаю что тут пояснять. Просто создать seesionscoped bean и записывать, извлекать из него параметры. Вроде flash-а, но без автоматической очистки.

Comment: не получается. commandButton находится на первой странице, при обращении к бину taskDetailsBean - он создается и параметр видно и он даже присваивается, но при переходе на страницу с деталями, бин, по всей видимости, создается повторно и там уже, в новом экземпляре параметра нет. taskDetailsBean - RequestScoped
Я, скорее всего, принципиально неправильно подхожу к решению.. вот только как правильно.. найти пока не могу

Comment: На task_details переходит редиректом что ли?

Comment: да, редиректом.

Comment: Тогда конечно будет новый запрос. Но есть несколько вариантов как передать параметр дальше через редирект

Comment: ну вот .. а самое интересное и не написал)))))) о каких вариантах идет речь?

Comment: @evp написал всё, что знал

Comment: Спасибо, Сергей. Получилось. только одно "Но" - никаким образом не получалось передать get-параметры. просто не работало и все. Не появлялись параметры в адресной строке, хотя функция их честно возвращала
    return "task_details?taskId=" + taskId;
я вместо h:commandButton на странице использовал h:button
в ней, соответственно установил 
    outcome="#{mainBean.showTaskDetail(task.dbID)}" includeViewParams="true"
после этого заработала адресная строка, ну и в RequestScoped бине моем, в конструкторе, уже словил этот параметр.

Comment: @evp Значит никакого редиректа на само деле никогда не было. Сразу показалось подозрительным. Но раз говорите редирект, подумал, что настроен через navigation-rules в faces-config.xml. А botton и commandbutton довольно сильно отличаются. В данном случае по счастливому стечению обстоятельств это привело к желаемому эффекту. Но не стоит обманываться. Они совсем не взаимозаменяемы. Ответ поправил, чтобы работало с commandbutton. Параметр `faces-redirect=true` в return сделает редирект. Должно работать из commandbutton и без конструктора, по первому варианту.

Comment: @evp 'button' - это просто ссылка на другую страницу. 'commanbutton' - это отправка формы, POST запрос. Выполнение на сервере какого-то action, который в итоге скажет на какую страницу идти дальше. Может button как раз то, что нужно в данном Вашем случае.